# Elliptic Regularity in Sobolev Spaces with Negative Order $(s<0)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I am looking for an elliptic regularity theorem in the Sobolev Space $H^s(\mathbb R^3)$ for $s<0$. In fact we have the equation $$A\,u=f,$$ where $A$ is an elliptic operator and $f\in H^s(\mathbb R^3)$ with $s<0$.

Can we deduce that $u\in H^{s+2}(\mathbb R^3)$?

I am also looking for a good reference in Elliptic Regularity please.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Any assumptions about $A$? Divergence form or not? Smooth coefficients?

Comment: $A\,u=-\Delta\,u+\,u,$

Comment: Use the Fourier transform or eigenfunctions.